# Jquery code, records how many clicks a link has than changes its url

Tags: jquery

maybe you can help

On my blog i have a link which is repeated inside a loop, lets say:

```
<a href="mysite.com/post" target="_blank" class="myclass">My link</a>
```

Is there a way, maybe a jquery code that counts how many times a visitor clicks on the link with the class "myclass"; lets say after he clicks three times, I can change the target of the link from "mysite.com/post" to something else, another url.

Any ideeas how I can do this?

Ty very much!

Comment: yes, in a single page load. the link has target blank, so which every click a page appears, see's it.. the jquery should reccord how many clicks , and after 3, change the url. can this be done?

Comment: If you are trying to do spam-prevention, you can't trust any thing done in javascript to accomplish it.

Comment: add a onclick event to a self-made function that keeps a counter for the given class, then when it reaches 3 you edit the attribute (href) via jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
var times_clicked = 0;
$('a.myclass').live('click', function() {
    times_clicked++;
    if (times_clicked > 5) {
        alert('too much man... too much');
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://toomuch.com');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
var counter = 0;
$(function() {
   $('.myclass').live('click', function() {
       counter++;
       // point to google after 3 clicks
       if(counter == 3) {
          $(this).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
       }
   });
});
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YGSE8/

Comment: What's the difference between the .live and using a .click on the element?

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom live binds the click event to new elements that could be added to the dom .click does not.

Comment: `.live` works with links that are dynamically added with that class. It's probably not needed in this case. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: .click() is a shortbcut for a .bind('click, function() {}) call, .live works a bit differently than .bind: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Hello, please tell me, if I want to add a variable instead of google.com, how can I do it?